# WCF Service Method always Async

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, viewmodel, prism

**I have a problem with calling a method from my DataService in my ViewModel.**
The problem is, that every method I create in my DataServicd- Implementation gets Async in my ViewModel, so i can not get any data from it. 
I am not so familiar with WCF so I am not able to solve the problem at my own.

*This is the DataService-Interface:*

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataService
{

    [OperationContract]
    ObservableCollection<object> GetStartPageKPIObjects();

    [OperationContract]
    Object DoSomething();
}
```

*This is my DataService Implementation*

```
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> GetStartPageKPIObjects()
    {
        ObservableCollection<object> tempItems = new ObservableCollection<object>();

        .........tempItems.add(...)
        .........tempItems.add(...)

        return tempItems;
    }




    public object DoSomething()
    {
        return new Object();
    }
}
```

*This is how I get the Object Reference to the DataService:*

```
******.ServiceReference.DataServiceClient dataClient = new ******.ServiceReference.DataServiceClient();
```

**Now, I would like to access the data from my Service:**

```
dataClient.GetStartPageKPIObjectsAsync();
dataClient.DoSomethingAsync();
```

But both return `(awaitable) Task<object>`! How do I now get the Data from the Service?

Answer (score 0):

There are non-async methods as well, maybe you didn't see them. You can turn off generation of async methods in the service ref settings. Then they disappear completely.

Comment: No, that is the problem, i can not turn them off because i am programming a windows store app and there you can not disable the asynchronous things.

Comment: OK, can you call Task.Result or Task.Wait on those tasks? Is that possible in Windows Store? Probably you should use await, though. It's great in GUI apps.

Comment: Yes, I can!  Result is possible!

Comment: Yeah, that would be a quick fix. You can use synchronous operations in Store apps as well but it seems to be harder.